# INDEX MATCH Three Cells

Tags: excel, csv

If a class was dropped, it should say **Drop** in `column B`.

There's a row for when a person registered and a row if they dropped the class. Clint McCobb is the only person who will have a value in column B. He registered for a class and then dropped it.

The `Name, Item ID, and Price` columns must match. Not sure how to match price considering there's a positive and a negative. If these columns match, the indexed value from `column C` will return to `column B`.

I know very little about Excel and tried to piece together the below function. It should be placed in `column B`.

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A2=$A$2:$A$10)*(D2=$D2:$D$10)*(E2=$E$2:$E$10),0))

A                B          C        D       E
Name          |  Dropped |  Type  |  Price | Item ID |
==============================================================
Joe Smith     |          |  Class |   50   |  350    |
Bob Parker    |          |  Drop  |  -9    |  350    |
Clint McCobb  |  Drop    |  Class |   10   |  70     |
Clint McCobb  |          |  Drop  |  -10   |  70     |
Hannah Smith  |          |  Class |   5    |  311    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If I understand your question correctly, you want to return the value from `column C to B`.  I also assume you always have the `Type column` sorted with first `Class` and then `Drop`.

This **array formula** (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together inside formula bar) can get your result:

```
=IF(ROW()=MAX(--($A$2:$A$6=A2)*--($E$2:$E$6=E2)*(ROW($A$2:$A$6))),"",INDEX($C$1:$C$6,MAX(--($A$2:$A$6=A2)*--($E$2:$E$6=E2)*(ROW($A$2:$A$6)))))
```

What this does is first to find matches with `Name` and `Item ID` (you can add more), then return the max row number of the duplicated record, and lookup the record using `INDEX`.  Please let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This works. Thank you! Is there any way to match the price column as well, even though it would have to match a positive price with a negative price?

Comment: Replace `--($A$2:$A$6=A2)*--($E$2:$E$6=E2)` with --($A$2:$A$6=A2)*--($E$2:$E$6=E2)*($D$2:$D$6=D2)`.  You can wrap ($D$2:$D$6=D2) with `ABS` such as `(ABS($D$2:$D$6)=ABS(D2))` so it will be always treated as positive numbers if you want.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do the hyphens do?

Comment: @JoshKern, good question.  Normally when you compare, you will see either `true or false` when evaluating the formula.  However, that evaluate formula screen is so small, in order to see more in that small window, add two dashes `--` will make `true and false` to `0 and 1`.  You can remove those dashes if you want.  It just my personal preference to add them for debugging or reviewing outcome.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I had an idea to only index if the C column = "Drop", so I tried the following without success: `=IF(ROW()=MAX(($F$2:$F$10=F6)*($H$2:$H$10=H6)*(ABS($N$2:$N$10)=ABS(N6))*($J$2:$J$10="Drop")*(ROW($F$2:$F$10))),"",INDEX($J$1:$J$10,MAX(($F$2:$F$10=F6)*($H$2:$H$10=H6)*(ABS($N$2:$N$10)=ABS(N6))*($J$2:$J$10="Drop")*(ROW($F$2:$F$10)))))`

Comment: I am not sure what you meant.  Do you mean this formula doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using COUNTIFS

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A4,C:C,"Drop",D:D,-D4,E:E,E4),"Drop","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try following formula and see if it works for you.

In cell B2:

`=IFERROR(IF(D2>0,LOOKUP(2,1/((A2&(0-D2)&E2)=($A$2:$A$6&$D$2:$D$6&$E$2:$E$6)),$C$2:$C$6),""),"")`

Copy down. Adjust Range part (*$A$2:$A$6&$D$2:$D$6&$E$2:$E$6)),$C$2:$C$6*) to cover actual range.